Redirect to URL upon clicking the SPFx app added to sitecontent in a site
I have an SPFx application which I am adding to my site. After adding to my site it appears in site-content.
Now on clicking the app, nothing happens. How to make to redirect to some page/url upon clicking?
Is there a way to achieve this using SPFx deployed on SP online.

Do you mean you click the app in site-contents?

Yes. My App is listed over there after adding.

From your description, it seems that you are using SPFx webpart, you need to go to the page to add the corresponding SPFx webpart and then use it.
I suggest you read the official documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

One can use Application customizer extension to achieve this.
